# how to prove the Lemma 5.6. of "Invitation to 3D vision"

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, rotations, matrix-exponential, skew-symmetric-matrices

In the proof of Lemma 5.6 on page 115, there are some points which I am not quite clear, as shown in the figure:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DWOd.png)

I don't quite understand the proof ,in the line part of the figure. Concretely about How to deduce the formula 5.8 in detail

Answer (score 0):

You already know $R=e^{\hat{\omega}\theta}$, and the proof has just shown that $\omega = \pm \frac{T}{||T||}$. Hence $R=\exp\left(\pm\hat{T}\frac{\theta}{||T||}\right)$. Then since for any matrix $A$ and constant $c$, $e^{cA}$ commutes with $A$, it follows that $R$ commutes with $\hat{T}$. So (5.7) becomes $R^2\hat{T} = \hat{T}$, which gives (5.8).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how to prove "for any matrix $A$  and constant $c$ , $e^{cA} $ commutes with A"?

Comment: $A^n$ commutes with $A$ for any $n$ (is this clear to you?), and therefore $e^{cA} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c^n}{n!}A^n$ commutes with $A$.

Comment: "for any matrix $A$  and constant $c$ , $e^{cA}$  commutes with A" is that $Ae^{cA}=e^{cA}A$,in which $A$ is the skew symmetry matrix, i.e., "$A^{T} = -A$".

Comment: It's $Ae^{cA} = e^{cA}A$ for *any* matrix (not just skew symmetric ones). In this case of course, $\hat{T}$ is skew symmetric.